# Mongo Spring Projection Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

Hi I am trying to get the below mongo query into spring mongo. I've been trying different ways but I am very fusturated right now. Need help!

```
db.getCollection('rate_review').aggregate([ 
   {$match:{stars:{$exists:true}}},
   {$group:{_id:"$store_id",count:{$sum:"$stars"}, maxCount:{$sum:1}}},
   { $project: { _id: 1, rating: 
       { 
        $divide: [ "$count", 
           {
               $multiply: [ "$maxCount", 5 ]
           }
         ] 
       },
       "timestamp":{$add:new Date()} } }
])
```

This is what  I have so far,

```
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("stars").exists(true)),
            group("$storeId").sum("$stars").as("count").sum("$stars").as("maxCount")
    ).withOptions(newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build()), StoreReview.class, Object.class).getMappedResults();
```

I need help with the Projection piece.

Comment: and where is `StoreReview` class?

Comment: if you need projection on `_id` you should know after group operation, you can select one of the records data. for example if you sort record by date and group with name, `first(...)` is selecting latest record field.